Passing variable from shell script to another script using expect
I'm trying to write a script to be able to pass a variable using script_a.sh which extract a value from the database to pass another script script_b.sh which uses this value as part of the input for another script test123 on a remotehost. However, the value appeared as a new line instead of the same line as the script name test123 which resulted in failing to execute the script i.e.
Current output of Commandline on remotehost:
userid@remotehost$ test123
userid@remotehost$ 456
Expected output Commandline on remotehost:
userid@remotehost$ test123 456
script_a.sh: To extract value from database:
#!/bin/bash
SQL_QUERY= select value from table A
SQL_OUTPUT= $(sqlplus -S username/pwd@database <<EOF
set heading off;
set feedback off;
$SQL_QUERY
exit;
EOF)

sh script_b.sh "$SQL_OUTPUT"

script_b.sh: To ssh to a remote server to run call a script test123 with input variable $SQL_OUTPUT from script a (assuming $SQL_OUTPUT = 456)
#!/bin/sh
SQL_OUTPUT=$1

/usr/local/bin/expect <<-EOF

spawn ssh userid@remotehost
expect "*"
send "password\n"
expect "*"
send "test123 ${SQL_OUTPUT}\n"
expect "*"
send "exit\n"

expect eof
EOF

Commandline on remotehost:
userid@remotehost$ test123
userid@remotehost$ 456

Hence, would like to check how to obtain the output as below i.e. 456 appearing in same line as test123:
userid@remotehost$ test123 456
Thank you.

You have obvious syntax errors. Please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

add declare -p SQL_OUTPUT before sh script_b.sh "$SQL_OUTPUT" and see what it outputs.
